# Visual C++ book for digital image processing

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing

Can anyone refer me to a book for Visual C++ in the area of "digital image processing"?

Comment: "Its urgent... " - maybe for you.....

Comment: be specific what kind of processing you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For computer vision in general, I would recommend [Learning OpenCV](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130) - it covers a lot of the basics of computer vision and the OpenCV library, and it's very understandable throughout.

The examples are in C, but that shouldn't be a problem, because they're there for you to follow along and understand rather than copy-paste.

Comment: @tina: The [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) library is designed for computer vision tasks - what exactly are you trying to achieve?